# Using DataBinding library for binding events that needs other components

Tags: java, android

I've just learned the Databinding for Android Java. So I did it like so in my activity.

```
activityAddOverTimeBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add_over_time);
        activityAddOverTimeBinding.setOvertime(overTime);
        handlers = new AddOvertimeClickHandlers(this);
        activityAddOverTimeBinding.setClickHandler(handlers);
```

and created an inner class inside this activity like so:

```
public class AddOvertimeClickHandlers{
        private Context context;

        public AddOvertimeClickHandlers(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void onSubmitButtonClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and in my xml, I made it like this:

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="overtime"
            type="com.anushka.androidtutz.contactmanager.db.entities.OverTimeDto" />
        <variable
            name="click_handler"
            type="com.sample.android.overtimetracker.userinterfaces.AddOverTime.AddOvertimeClickHandlers" />
    </data>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="@string/submit_button"
            android:onClick="@{click_handler::onSubmitButtonClick}"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.605"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

This is actually working. But my concern is; since the click handler is in another class, how can I access the different components of my activity since this is a part of my logic on clicking a button? To better illustrate, below is how I coded it without putting the "click handlers" on a different class.

```
activityAddOverTimeBinding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(overTime.getTitle())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(overTime.getDescription())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Description cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(overTime.getStartDate())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start time cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(overTime.getEndDate())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End time cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String title = overTime.getTitle();
                String description = overTime.getDescription();
                String startTime = overTime.getStartDate();
                String endTime = overTime.getEndDate();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("description", description);
                intent.putExtra("startTime", startTime);
                intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

The `overTime` object is in my activity class and it is "Databinded". So my AddOvertimeClickHandlers class doesn't know anything if it has changed or if it has values. Even if I place the `OverTime` Class in the constructor, it wont change if this object changes in my activity class. Probably I can use an interface so the overtime object will be updated as well in my AddOvertimeClickHandlers but, it will make my program more complicated than just  placing the whole event listeners in my activity class and skip the AddOvertimeClickHandlers. Am I thinking this right? Can you tell me how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take whatever current value of `overtime` is whenever a click occurs through the databinding.

Just update this code :

```
public class AddOvertimeClickHandlers{

    public AddOvertimeClickHandlers() {
    }

    public void onSubmitButtonClick(@NonNull View v, @Nullable OverTime overtime){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Xml :

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="overtime"
            type="com.anushka.androidtutz.contactmanager.db.entities.OverTimeDto" />
        <variable
            name="click_handler"
            type="com.sample.android.overtimetracker.userinterfaces.AddOverTime.AddOvertimeClickHandlers" />
    </data>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="@string/submit_button"
            android:onClick="@{v -> click_handler.onSubmitButtonClick(v, overtime)}"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.605"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

This way your listener/handler `AddOvertimeClickHandlers` has the arguments it needs to perform internal logic on the function call.